# How to calculate running balance in SQL Server query?

Tags: sql-server

I have data in given format:

```
Id  | Total_Inv_Amount  | Total_Rec_Inv_Amount  | Invoice_No    Invoice_Amont   | Payment_Outstanding   | Refund_Outstanding   
1   | 25000 | 22000 | 5 | 15000 | 0 | 0   
1   | 25000 | 22000 | 6 | 10000 | 0 | 0   
2   | 45000 | 48000 | 10| 25000 | 0 | 0   
2   | 45000 | 48000 | 15| 20000 | 0 | 0
```

> expected result ....

```
Id  | Total_Inv_Amount  | Total_Rec_Inv_Amount  | Invoice_No    Invoice_Amont   | Payment_Outstanding   | Refund_Outstanding   
1   | 25000 | 22000 | 5 | 15000 | 0     | 0   
1   | 25000 | 22000 | 6 | 10000 | 3000  | 0   
2   | 45000 | 48000 | 10| 25000 | 0     | 0   
2   | 45000 | 48000 | 15| 20000 | 0     | 2000
```

> Calculation :--
>    invoice No 5 & 6 Total Amount is : 15000+10000 = 25000
>    And total Received Amount is : 22000
>
> now in field Payment_Outstanding   for invoice no is 0
>    because total_invoice_amt > invoice 5 amount 
>    22000 >15000 than payment outstanding is 0
>    remain amount is 22000-15000 = 7000
>
> now deduct this amount from next invoice which amount is 10000
>
> 10000-7000 = 3000 this is payment outstanding
>
> now please help me how to calculate this in query

Comment: Could you add also expected output ?

Comment: please check fields Payment_Outstanding and Refund_Outstanding

Comment: i those fields i have to calculate values

Comment: To understand, how to calculate running balance, please explain how you calculate balance in one row, your example is absolutely unclear.

Comment: in this case as you can see ,

total invoice amount is 25000 and total receive amount is 22000

total invoice amount comes from 15000+10000 = 25000

Comment: Can't you use group by using Id, sum by Invoice_Amont and then - recived amount?

Comment: no this is not work

Answer (score 0):

recursive queries are great at getting running values.
The first cte adds a rownumber which is used by the recursive part. In the recursive part the calculations are done. In het final result, values below 0 won't be displayed.

```
Declare @myTable table (Id int, Total_Inv_Amount float,
    Total_Rec_Inv_Amount float,Invoice_No int,   
    Invoice_Amount float, Payment_Outstanding float, 
    Refund_Outstanding float)

insert into @myTable values
(1   , 25000 , 22000 , 5 , 15000 , 0 , 0  ), 
(1   , 25000 , 22000 , 6 , 10000 , 0 , 0  ), 
(2   , 45000 , 48000 , 10, 25000 , 0 , 0  ), 
(2   , 45000 , 48000 , 15, 20000 , 0 , 0  )

;with first_cte as
(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by invoice_no) rn
    from @myTable
)
, result_rte as
(
    select m.Id, m.Total_Inv_Amount,m.Total_Rec_Inv_Amount,
        m.Invoice_No,   m.Invoice_Amount, m.Payment_Outstanding, 
        m.Refund_Outstanding, m.rn, invoice_Amount TotalAmount
    from first_cte m
    where rn = 1
    union all
    select m.Id, m.Total_Inv_Amount,m.Total_Rec_Inv_Amount,
        m.Invoice_No,   m.Invoice_Amount,  
        r.TotalAmount + m.Invoice_Amount - m.Total_Rec_Inv_Amount , 
        m.Total_Rec_Inv_Amount - (r.TotalAmount + m.Invoice_Amount), 
        m.rn, r.TotalAmount + m.Invoice_Amount
    from result_rte r
    join first_cte m on r.id = m.id and r.rn+1 = m.rn
)

select Id, Total_Inv_Amount,Total_Rec_Inv_Amount,Invoice_No,   Invoice_Amount, 
    case when Payment_Outstanding > 0 then Payment_Outstanding else 0 end Payment_Outstanding  , 
    case when Refund_Outstanding > 0 then Refund_Outstanding else 0 end Refund_Outstanding
from result_rte order by invoice_no
```